# Assign MS Project Resources parameters in one line C#

Tags: c#, ms-project

I'm not sure if what i'm trying to do is achievable. I am trying to assign different types of parameters to a resource. For example i am trying to define the "Type" of the resource as such:

`project.Resources.Add(RESOURCE_NAME, i).Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjResourceTypes.pjResourceTypeMaterial`

My question is that can i add MaterialLabel and other parameters in the same line of code without the need of referencing the resource on a different line and assigning the MaterialLabel to it?

Comment: This works in VBA. Try it in C# and update your question with relevant details if you get an error.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer Rachel. My question is how can i try it in C#? What is the syntax?

Comment: That is the syntax. Try it as you would any code in C#. And check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good questions would have a relevant code and a description of what isn't working along with error information, etc.